# converting data from surface View into Jpeg

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapimage

Hi i'm capturing frames from surface View and have Task to covert it to jpg and save to file. But i can`t release memory. After few seconds i have OutOfMemoryExc. Here id my Async:

```
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... frames) {

            byte[] data = frames[0];

            int[] imagePixels = convertYUV420_NV21toRGB8888(data, mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);
            Bitmap bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imagePixels, mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmapImage.recycle();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOs);

            bitmapImage.recycle();
            System.gc();
            OutputStream os = null;

            boolean imageSaved = true;

            try {
                os = new FileOutputStream(FileService.generateFrameFile());
                os.write(byteArrayOs.toByteArray());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                imageSaved = false;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(bitmapImage != null) {
                        bitmapImage.recycle();
                    }
                    if(byteArrayOs != null) {
                        byteArrayOs.close();
                    }
                    if (os != null) {
                        os.flush();
                        os.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    imageSaved = false;
                }
            }
            mCallback.onTaskCompleted(imageSaved);

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Show the code that launch the task, what frequency are you using to capture frames ?

Comment: new SaveFrameTask(previewSize.height, previewSize.width, new OnTaskCompleted<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(Boolean data) {
                if(data) {
                    mFramesCount++;
                }
            }
        }).execute(data);

10 times per second

Comment: If you're launching new `SaveFrameTask`each time `SurfaceView` renders a new frame then you will be in trouble since the `SurfaceView` will produce more frames than the time each task takes to handle one frame so you will run out of memory.  Besides the fact of using `execute` and not `executeOnExecutor` which  execute serially on a single thread on api >= 11 (HONEYCOMB`) and api < 1.6 ( `DONUT`)

Comment: i've set 10 FPS. And process time isn't problem. Problem is that Bitmap seams to doesn't release memory.

Comment: with 10 FPS you mean you try to process 10 frames in parallel ?

Comment: i mean that i have new frame each 1/10 sec. I need to catch frames and when user clicks i need to save frames from last 10 seconds. Don't have any idea how to do this correctly.